# Can someone provide me an intuitive explaination to uniqueness theorem in electrostatics?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

So far I understood that in one dimension Laplace equation gives out a simple equation $V(x)=mx+b$ which is because if you differentiate this equation two times you will get 0 which is Laplace identity.

After this it says(Griffiths Electrodynamics) *thus we need two boundary conditions* What does this mean?

In my understanding, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two solutions two the Laplace equation for potential. And thus$\nabla^2 V=0$ is satisfied by thee. Then it takes potential at a third point which is the difference of $V_1$ and $V_2$ and thus 
taking Laplacian of $V_3=V_1-V_2$ gives us zero and thus $V_3$ also satisfies the Laplacian
and after than whatever he has written I am sorry I don't understand?

Whats the sole purpose of Uniqueness Theorem and Boundary conditions, where and how do we use it?

I went through Rochester and Ph Texas online notes got nothing

Then it provides this proof

He says *there may be islands inside* what does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an intuitive sense, the uniqueness theorem says that the solution to the Poisson equation is *unique* - which means once you have a $V$, no matter how you get it, and it solves the equations and the boundary conditions, that **is** the solution you are looking for.

I will give a more detailed response to your other questions soon.

Comment: what are boundary conditions ? I mean does it refer to orientation of anything else

Comment: The Poisson's equation needs to have boundary conditions to be solved. These are the potentials on the surfaces.

Comment: well I am too much frustated that I forgot latex code for nabla

Comment: No worries about that.

Comment: I don't know what are boundary conditions can You give an example that what does it mean ?

Comment: $\nabla^2V=0$ is a 2nd order equation, so it needs two boundary conditions. E.g., you can specify the $V$ at infinity, and on the surface $\mathcal{S}$ in your Fig. 3.5.

Comment: sir I am asking what are boundary conditions ?

Comment: @user197766 Not to put to fine a point on it, but they are conditions on the boundary. Imagine the head of a drum. It can vibrate in the middle, but it is firmly attached to the mouth of the drum. That circle where the drum skin is glued to the edge is the boundary and the fact that it is glued down is the condition. You need to tell me what is going on with V at the edge of the volume (i.e. the boundary) before I can tell you the solution to Poisson's Equation.

Comment: I see. Boundary conditions means specifying the value of the function (that you are trying to solve for) at some specific points.

Comment: okay so for first uniqueness theorem he specifies that two values of potential V1 and V2 satisfies Laplacian equation.Are these boundary condition @geoffrey well I have read that its like things go smoothly and fell of at the edge so I think potential just tends to 0 at infinity

Comment: There you go Jadhavpur Univ. boy.Perhaps I should drop my IIT JAM dream.It is taking me too long to develop thoughts and diagrams fast.Although I understood that the sole purpose of proof was to show that there would be only single value of potential which will satisfy the equation.